# Can I use Vlookup and CountA in Google Sheets to query how many non-empty cells are in Column B that all have the same value as in column A?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, vlookup, countif

I'm trying to find a way to know how many non-empty cells are in column B, for all rows in which there is one same value in Column A.

e.g. Column A Row 1-5 is value "1", I want know how many nonempty cells are next to the value "1".

I want to do the same thing, but instead of counta, I want to do it for countif as well for columns C, and D for various values (countif(C2:C, "Banana"

The ultimate goal is being able to delete and add rows without breaking the formula and copy paste the formula to easily make new batches.

Here is my example sheet I'm working on. I can't figure out how to make vlookup or array work for me here, I'm not very good at this.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PxP2pOyV916HWVGHjOsLUDwZN2lcGQ6PrBuzDqigwO8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What exactly should column C and column D contain?

Comment: Somebody has erased all datas !!

Comment: @MikeSteelson I left it empty, I'll add data now. Your table works for the count of fruit, that's awesome, thank you so much. Is it possible to use TCD and this formula for counting seeds/non-seeds, citrus/non-citrus?

Comment: @LearningMathematics For all of the fruits in basket 1 (A2:A6) I want to know how many are non-citrus/citrus, and also how many have seeds/no seeds. The trick is I don't want to manually "Countif "seeds"" etc. for every range of rows. 

It would be feasible to manually use countif for every range of rows if I had the same number of fruit in every basket, but I don't.

Comment: @o ril ... play with TCD, add column citrus/non citrus. See the second sheet. Learn TCD, it is a very usefull tool.

Comment: Sorry, TCD = pivot table in English

Answer (score 1):

Complete column A with

```
=ArrayFormula(lookup(row(A2:A),row(A2:A)/if(A2:A<>"",1,0),A2:A))
```

and then perform Pivot Table as you wish